# How do I prevent my javascript locking up the browser?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a `WebSocket` that receives data at a rate of ~50hz. Each time an update is pushed to the browser, it turns the JSON data it's had published to it into some pretty charts.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Connecting web socket for status publishing')
    allRawDataPublisher = new ReconnectingWebSocket("ws://" + location.host + '/raw/allrawdata');

    var rawUnprocessedData = [];

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        rawUnprocessedData.push({x:i, y:0});
    }

    var unprocessedRawChart = new CanvasJS.Chart("rawUnprocessedData",{
        title :{ text: "Raw Unprocessed Data"},
        axisX: { title: "Bin"},
        axisY: { title: "SNR"},
        data: [{ type: "line", dataPoints : rawUnprocessedData},{ type: "line", dataPoints : noiseFloorData}]
    });

    var updateChart = function (dps, newData, chart) {
        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
          dps[i].y = newData[i];
        }
        chart.render();
    };

    allRawDataPublisher.onmessage = function (message) {
        jsonPayload = JSON.parse(message.data);
        var dataElements = jsonPayload["Raw Data Packet"]
        updateChart(rawUnprocessedData, dataElements["RAW_DATA"].Val, unprocessedRawChart)
    };

    unprocessedRawChart.render();
});
```

This works great when my laptop is plugged into a power socket but if I unplug the power, my laptop drops it's processing power (and the same issue occurs on lower-specc'd tablets, phones etc). When there's less processing power available, the browser (Chrome) completely locks up.

I'm guessing the javascript is receiving updates faster than the browser can render them and consequently locking the tab up.

If the browser is unable to update at the requested rate, I would like it to drop new data until it's ready to render a new update. Is there a standard way to check the browser has had enough time to render an update and drop new frames if that's not the case?

*[Edit]

I did some digging with Chrome's profiler which confirms that (as expected) it's re-drawing the chart that is taking the bulk of the processing power.

Comment: Just another question, I wondered, will putting this code into setTimeout() call do seperate the browser process and websocket process?

Comment: @TahaPaksu `setTimeout` won't start a separate process of any sort - it simply makes the execution of the callback async

Comment: Yep, but will it prevent the blocking of the page somehow?

Comment: I doubt it but I'm not 100% sure - I guess the event queue will still be flooded - at some point those `setTimeout`s will expire and invoke their callbacks thus leading back to the same issue

Comment: You should read up on [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) and [Debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

Comment: @David WebWorkers don't have access to the DOM nor the main execution context so you can't offload rendering work there. Debouncing won't work since the data comes in regular intervals with no guarantee that it will stop at the correct point so that the debouncer will fire (a throttle function would work however). OP seems to need real-time updates of the entire data sequence

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to do too much processing at 50Hz in the main thread.  You can offload networking, parsing and compute time to a webWorker, but not rendering or DOM work.  So, it depends upon how much time different parts of the process are taking on whether it would help to use a webWorker or not.  Mostly, I'm guessing that you need to pare down the flood of data you're trying to process so you don't have so much to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do work between frames by using `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

The callback passed to this function will be called at a maximum of 60 times a second - or whichever number matches the refresh rate of your display.

It's also guaranteed to be called *before* the next repaint - and *after* the previous repaint has finished.

From [MDN window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

> The window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser call a specified function to update an animation before the next repaint. The method takes a callback as an argument to be invoked before the repaint.

Here's an example on how it's used:

```js
function renderChart () {
   // pull data from your array and do rendering here
   console.log('rendering...')
   requestAnimationFrame(renderChart)
}

requestAnimationFrame(renderChart)
```

---

However, it's better to render changes to your graph in *batches*, instead of doing rendering work for every single datum that comes through or on every frame.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/1294/) using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) code that:

- Pushes data to an `Array` every 100ms (10 Hz)
- Renders data, in batches of 4 - every 1000ms (1 Hz)

---

```
const values = []
const ctx = document.getElementById('chartContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['start'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'mm of rain',
      data: [1],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  }
});

// Push 1 item every 100ms (10 Hz), simulates 
// your data coming through at a faster
// rate than you can render
setInterval(() => {
  values.push(Math.random())
}, 100)

// Pull last 4 items every 1 second (1 Hz)
setInterval(() => {
  // splice last 4 items, add them to the chart's data
  values.splice(values.length - 4, 4)
    .forEach((value, index) => {
      chart.data.labels.push(index)
      chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(value)
    })

  // finally, command the chart to update once!
  chart.update()
}, 1000)
```

Do note that the above concept needs to handle exceptions appropriately, otherwise the `values` `Array` will start accumulating so much data that the process runs out of memory.

You also have to be careful in the way you render your batches. If your value render rate is slower than the rate at which you fill the `values` `Array`, you will eventually run into memory issues.

Last but not least: I'm not really convinced you ever need to update a piece of data faster than 2 Hz, as I doubt the human brain can make useful interpretations at such a fast rate.

Comment: This seems like a more logical approach; detaching the drawing updates from the data influx and stopping that down to the rate the browser can handle.

Comment: Yes - however that's by no means a guarantee that you'll get a smooth UX overall. The browser would still be busy trying to do rendering all the time which leaves a small amount of CPU cycles(oversimplified for brevity) for other stuff. You might also want to consider the 'batch' approach I've mentioned in my answer, if your delta between datums is small enough

Comment: I can see how I'd simply store the latest result but how would you suggest triggering processing a batch to run at 10hz for example?

Comment: I guess something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/q5qeweqe/5/) - It's very crude code but I'd do something like that. You might want to experiment with rendering batches of 3 or 4 instead of just 2

Comment: Also I should have asked that beforehand but - have you profiled your code to make sure that it's the rendering that causes the locks?

Comment: I ended up using `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval` to do the chart updates and separated the chart updating into that timeout which solved my issue. Now the browser doesn't lock up, it just does as many updates as it can and drops the rest. Here's a fiddle demonstrating some of that: https://jsfiddle.net/g05xcx0g/9/ ..although it's also generating data in there for the purposes of the demo

Comment: that's a nice solution - probs better than mine